# how to debounce a final-form Field?

Tags: reactjs, throttling, debouncing, react-final-form, final-form

this is a pretty common query, but I am a bit confused with the new `final-form` library. I used to work with `redux-form` but this new version is too different.

My need is simple, I want to dispatch a search as the user writes in some text, but I want to add a `throttle` to the Field.

Here is a first attempt with the lib `react-final-form-listeners`, but as you will see, when you write in the text field, the debounce does not work :/

https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-final-form-simple-example-khkof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First, I'd encourage you to do all of this without using an obscured package layer. This will help you truly understand the flow**, but nevertheless, here's how you can call a function when the input changes:

- debounce (only executes once when a user stops typing for 500ms)
- throttle (batches then executes every 500ms)
- normal (executes on every input update)

In this case, I just created a debounced function outside of the render method. This varies when using classes instead of hooks:

Hooks:

```
const handleSearch = debounce(searchText => { ... }, 500);
```

Classes (or you can debounce the class field in the `constructor`, either work):

```
class Example extends Component {
  handleSearch = debounce(searchText => { ... }, 500)

  render = () => { ... }
}
```

**Working example**  (type while the codesandbox console is open):

[image: Edit React Final Form - Simple Example]

---

The differences between debounced, throttled, and normal execution:

[image]

---

Same as above, minus `react-final-form` and `react-final-form-listeners` (two less dependencies in your project!):

**Working example** (type while the codesandbox console is open):

[image: Edit Simple Form - Simple Example]

---

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your solution:

- use lodash `debounce` instead of `throttle`.
- create debounced function outside form in order to prevent its reassign on every rerender or change
- call form submit action, instead of submit handler `handleSubmit`

Modified and working your example:

[image: Edit React Final Form - Simple Example]

Answer (score -1):

Here's a memoized debounced version:

```js
export default function DebouncedMemoizedField({
  milliseconds = 400,
  validate,
  ...props
}) {
  const timeout = useRef(null);
  const lastValue = useRef(null);
  const lastResult = useRef(null);

  const validateField = (value, values, meta) => new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (timeout.current) {
      timeout.current();
    }

    if (value !== lastValue.current) {
      const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
        lastValue.current = value;
        lastResult.current = validate(value, values, meta);
        resolve(lastResult.current);
      }, milliseconds);

      timeout.current = () => {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        resolve(true);
      };
    } else {
      resolve(lastResult.current);
    }
  });

  return <Field validate={validateField} {...props} />;
}
```

Usage:

```js
<MemoizedDebouncedValidationField
  name="username"
  validate={(value) => (value === 'jim' ? 'Username exists' : undefined)}
  render={({ input, meta }) => (
    <>
      <input {...input} />
      {(meta.touched && meta.error) && <p>Error</p>}
    </>
  )}
/>
```