# react-final-form validation not work with debounce

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, debouncing

I wrote simple async validation use react-final-form
In field username I typed john and show error Username taken!

I want to add debounce function from lodash library.
I typed john and couldn't see error add one symbol and error appear
When one symbol was removed (input value is john) error disappear

It's look like something is cached
Please help me understand my issue

FYI 
I created simple application : 
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-asynchronous-field-level-validation-example-iljh1?file=/index.js:477-492

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to debounce a final-form Field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57329357/how-to-debounce-a-final-form-field)

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to give view  access to project  for everyone

Comment: Omid Nikrah  Thank you for you link. This example only print in console.log but I need that return value